# XPath expression for selecting all nodes with all ancestors containing an attribute

Tags: xpath

I have a structure like this:

```
<root>
<n1 a='1'>
    <n2 a='1'>
        <n3 a='1'> - correct
        </n3>
    </n2>
</n1>

<n1 a='1'>
    <n2 a='1'>
        <n3 a='0'> - false
        </n3>
    </n2>
</n1>

<n1 a='0'>
    <n2 a='1'>
        <n3 a='1'> - false
        </n3>
    </n2>
</n1>

<n1 a='1'>
    <n2 a='0'>
        <n3 a='1'> - false
        </n3>
    </n2>
</n1>
</root>
```

but with variable depth.

The problem I have is to get only the first example - a node that each of its predecesors contains attribute a=1

It is easy to solve the second example:

```
.//*[@a='1']
```

But how can I avoid the third case that the attribute is somewhere else?

Comment: There are no ancestors in your XML. All nodes are siblings. (Also, your XML is syntactically invalid. Fix it first.)

Comment: Ok, I changed it to the XML.

Comment: Do you really want to select *all* qualifying elements (`//*`), including those that have element children? If so, then in your first example, the correct result would be the nodeset of `<n1>`, `<n2>`, and `<n3>`. Or do you only want leaf elements (i.e. elements with no children)?

Comment: Oh, you are right. I wanted only the leaf elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
//n1[not(n1) and not(ancestor-or-self::n1[@a=0])]
```

It means: the node itself is a leaf (no `n1` children), and it has no ancestor (including itself) with `a=0`.

To test, I used the following XML:

```
<r>
<n1 a='1'>
  <n1 a='1'>
    <n1 a='1'>yes</n1>
  </n1>
</n1>
<n1 a='1'>
  <n1 a='1'>
    <n1 a='0'>no 1</n1>
  </n1>
</n1>
<n1 a='0'>
  <n1 a='1'>
    <n1 a='1'>no 2</n1>
  </n1>
</n1>
</r>
```

and the following [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML::XSH2) script:

```
open file.xml ;
echo //n1[not(n1) and not(ancestor-or-self::n1[@a=0])] ;
```

Output: `yes`

### Update

For the new XML in your question, just replace `n1` with `*` in the query.

```
//*[not(*) and not(ancestor-or-self::*[@a=0])]
```

Comment: @ne2dmar: are you sure this works? It looks like it would return a false positive on your 2nd and 4th examples.

Comment: @LarsH: The input has changed.